# PHP - Detect URL (test.html?variable=1)

Tags: php, url, iframe, detect

I want to make a system that detects URL and changes one of the iframes URL.

I don't know PHP so much but I want to make something like this.

- Detect URL (link.com/page.html?ip=xxx)
- If it equals xxx change iframes (id = server) src to BLAHBLAH.COM or xxx (the variable that we detect)
- If it equals yyy change iframes (id = server) src to TEST.COM or yyy (the variable that we detect)

Note that I am not going to use 2 links. I am going to use multiple links. So If-Else would'nt works.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you share what you have tried and what problems you have run  into?

Answer (score 4):

A example from basic php for get the parameters of any url.

```
$servers = array
  (
  array(1,"serverxxx"),
  array(2,"serveryyy"),
  array(3,"serverzzz")
  );

 if(isset($_GET)){
     $params = array_keys($_GET);
     for( $i=0; $i<count( $params ); $i++ )
         if(isset( $_GET[$params[$i]]) ){
             for($j=o;$i<count($servers);$j++){
               $id =$_GET[$params[$i]];
               if($id==$server[$j]) {
                 $src = $server[$j][1]];
                 break;
               }       
             }
         }
 } ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to retrieve the URI after the domain name

Answer (score 0):

I made a play.php and write this simple code

```
<?php
echo '<iframe style="display: block; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;" width=100% height=100% src="' .htmlspecialchars($_GET["server"]). '" frameBorder="0">
        </iframe>'
?>
```

Whenever you type **play.php?server=//serverlink.com** it creates a iframe with that URL.